# Data copy from C++ to OpenGL works with custom container but not with std::tuple

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11

When I copy data from my own container to an OpenGL buffer everything works, but if I try with `std::tuple` it doesn't.

Consider my own container:

```
struct PositionColorTexture
{
    glm::vec4 position;
    glm::vec4 color;
    glm::vec2 texture;
}
```

And an `std::tuple` equivalent:

```
std::tuple<glm::vec4, glm::vec4, glm::vec2> tuple;
```

Data has the same size:

```
sizeof(PositionColorTexture) == 40 Bytes
sizeof(tuple) == 40 Bytes
```

both have the same size and after template deduction the data should be pretty much the same inside both but...

```
std::vector<PositionColorTexture> data = {...};

// copy data to an opengl buffer
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(PositionColorTexture) * data.size(), &data[0]);
```

that works well, however...

```
std::vector<std::tuple<glm::vec4, glm::vec4, glm::vec2>> data = {...};

// copy data to an opengl buffer
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(std::tuple<glm::vec4, glm::vec4, glm::vec2>) * data.size(), &data[0]);
```

the above doesn't work. Internally both should be pretty much the same right? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think `std::tuple` qualifies as a Plain Old Data (POD) type, so casting it to `void*` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The STL tuple definition makes no guarantee as to the order that the tuple elements will be stored in. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and if I store a tuple like this:

```
    std::tuple<float, float, float> ftuple = std::make_tuple(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
```

then I get this in the inspection window:

```
-       ((float*)&ftuple), 3    0x004dfe5c  float *
        [0] 3.00000000  float
        [1] 2.00000000  float
        [2] 1.00000000  float
```

You can see the order of data has been reversed. (This is because of the way STL tuples are implemented with recursive variadic templates.) My bet is that GL is expecting data in the position/color/texture order and your tuple data has been reversed to texture/color/position order.

My opinion: What you're doing can be done well and simply with a struct, and there's no gain in bothering with tuples.